# To find Range of roots of quadratic equation

Tags: roots, quadratics

I have been given the following quadratic equation and is asked to find the range of its roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, where $\alpha>\beta$
$$(k+1)x^2 - (20k+14)x + 91k +40 =0,$$ 
where $k>0$ .
Here's my approach.

I applied the quadratic formula for the roots and got.
$$\alpha=\frac{(10k+7) -3\sqrt{k^2+k+1}}{k+1}$$
Similarly
$$\beta=\frac{(10k+7)+3\sqrt{k^2+k+1}}{k+1}$$
But how to find the range. Please help

Comment: Your approach is correct. What is the definition of range? I would say range is just $\beta-\alpha$ since $\beta>\alpha$ as you wrote it.

Comment: I don't see that "range of its roots" has a well-defined meaning. Can you check whether that's exactly how the problem is stated? Or, check previous examples in this context. Otherwise, do they mean *ranges* of the roots as functions of $k,$ since we always want to have two distinct real roots? Or the range of values of $k$ for which there are distinct roots $\alpha, \beta$? These are things you need to clarify.

Comment: Well range means the set of values which$\alpha$ and $\beta$ can take. And the answer is in the form (a,b).

Comment: You can have an estimation of the ranges of the roots, by finding the location of roots in graph plotted.

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to find for what values of k such that the equation has real roots ($\alpha$ and $\beta$).

To this end, we set $(10k + 7)^2 \ge (k+1)((91k + 40)$

This is reduced to $k^2 + k + 1 \ge 0$.

The LHS has no real roots for k. In addition, $((k^2))$ is positive. That means the quadratic expression in k is positive definite (i.e. always bigger than 0).

Therefore, the given equation has real roots for all values of k (except possibly when k = -1).

Answer (score 0):

We know from the question that  $ \alpha > \beta $ ,using the Quadratic formula, the root with the positive sign will be $ \alpha $ and 
the one with the negative sign will be $ \beta $, which you have reversed in your
description.

$ \alpha = \frac{10k+7 + 3\sqrt{k^2 + k + 1}}{k + 1}$

and the other root will be $\beta$

After that, plot the graph of $ \alpha $ versus k, with k as the x-axis. 
The maximum value of that function for k > 0, will be the upper limit of
the range of the root.

Similarly, plot $ \beta $ versus k, with k as the x-axis. 
The minimum value of that function for k > 0, will be the lower limit of the
range of the root.

Comment: I don't think your answer is a very good solution to my question as well don't draw graphs of such complex equation that too rational equation.

Comment: @Abhinav well if you can't plot a graph then find the value of k where the derivative is 0. And put that value of k in the equation

Answer (score 0):

Your equation can be re-written as $$f(x)=(x-4)(x-10)+k(x-7)(x-13)$$
So it can be seen that

$f(4)=27k$

$f(7)=-9$

$f(10)=-9k$

$f(13)=27$

Since $f(7)$ and $f(13)$ are of opposite signs,clearly one root must be lying on the interval $(7,13)$.

Therefore we can say that another real root must also exist since in a quadratic equation with real coefficients complex/imaginary roots can only occur in conjugate pairs.

Hence the equation will have real roots for all real values of $k$